# What is the burning city referred to in the song "I'll Try" from the Tinker Bell and the Lost Treasure soundrack?

Tags: soundtrack, tinker-bell-and-the-lost-treasure

The song ["I'll Try" by Jessie McCartney](https://genius.com/Jesse-mccartney-ill-try-lyrics) from the soundtrack for *Tinker Bell and the Lost Treasure* features the lines

> My whole world is changin'
> I don't know where to turn
> I can't leave you waitin'
> But I can't stay and watch the city burn
> Watch it burn

What is the burning city that it refers to?

Is this a real city or a metaphor for something?

Answer (score 16):

The song was originally written and performed for [Return to Neverland (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Never_Land) by [Jonatha Brooke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonatha_Brooke) then later covered by Jessie McCartney and re-used in Tinker Bell and the Lost Treasure.

As Return to Neverland is written against the backdrop of London during the Blitz in World War II, there's a reasonable extrapolation could be made for this to be the city burning.

I can't find any reference online except for fan explanations.

Answer (score 1):

There are many references that could back up the verse 2 of this song, but the two that immediately came to my mind are:

1. The burning of [Sodom and Gomorrah](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodom_and_Gomorrah)
2. The burning of [Atlanta](https://youtu.be/PnEZrV_WT44)

In both cases, it refers to the end of an era, brought down by fire, the end of a changing world. And it doesn't mean anything to stand still watching something that is inevitable. You'd better move on. That really look like the case here: watch, it's burning, my world is falling down, I don't know what to do, but I can't stand watching, I have to do something.

Comment: This song from a Disney film from 15 or so years ago. Both of those seem a little political.

Comment: It's an image, nothing political in my opinion